# Mail forwarding in Microsoft Exchange Server 2007

Tags: email, exchange-2007, email-server, mail-forwarding

How do I forward messages to another domain using Exchange server? For example user@mydomain.blah i want to forward to someUser@gmail.com?

I tried this way: Right click on User mailbox acc->properties->Mail Flow Settings-> Delivery Options->Check Forward to->Click Browse. I get new window, but I can select only users from my domain!

I tried to add new contact object in Active Directory, but I can't see it when I try again process described earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contact must be mail enabled (meaning that it must have an email address). Otherwise, Exchange will ignore it when offering up mail destinations in the forwarding window.

Comment: I created new contact and put E-mail address in E-mail field, but still same problem

Comment: Have you mail enabled the contact by speicifying the "External e-mail address" like this Microsoft Example (How to Create a New Mail-Enabled User). http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125258(v=exchg.80).aspx  Just specifying the email address on the contact is not enough to "mail enable" it.